# Added a Samsung NVMe SSD, but I can't see it in File Explorer

Tags: 20.04, ssd, samsung, nvme

I run Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS that was installed on an a 256GB SSD. I got a new Samsung 1 TB NVMe SSD but I can't seem to access it from File Explorer.

In Settings-> About-> Disk Capacity = 1.2TB

In Disks:

```
Model: Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB (3B2QGXA7)
Size: 1,0 TB (1000204886016 bytes)
Partitioning: GUID Partition Table
Device: /dev/nvme0n1
Contents: Unallocated Space
```

How do I solve this step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least one partition with a file system.

Open the "**Disks**" application.

If the drive is not yet formatted, choose "**Format Disk...**"

Then select the disk and click the `+` button to add a new file system.  Read the prompts to choose a file system that is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it automatically mounts? Or i have to do something?

Comment: Is there a problem mounting?

Answer (score 1):

New disks need to be formatted.

Open the Disks app, select the new disk, click the 3-dots button and choose format.

Comment: Did that. Still cant see it in File Explorer

Comment: See if this helps you out https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2020/02/how-to-format-disk-drive-with-ubuntu-disk-utility.html